# iPhone in app Email format

Tags: ios, objective-c, email

Basically I have two sections in my app one call cars and the other call trucks each with 3 buttons. When one button is click it saves the truck or car details in nsuserdefault. Bascially I want to print it out in an email showing the cars and truck the user clicked on and show it in a specific format for example "Car:Car1,Car 2, Car 3 Truck: Truck1, Truck2 Truck 3".However, if the user clicked on 2 car buttons and one Truck button it looks like this  "Car:Car1,Car2,Truck1" Any tips on how to get around this will be appreciated.

```
              NSString *emailBody=[NSString                            
             stringWithFormat:@"Car:%@,%@,%@,Truck:%@,%@,%@",[[NSUserDefaults        
             standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"Car1"],[[NSUserDefaults 
             standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"Car2"],[[NSUserDefaults 
             standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"Car3"],[[NSUserDefaults 
             standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"Truck1"],[[NSUserDefaults 
             standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"Truck2"],
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"Truck3"]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NSString *emailBody=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Car:%@,%@,%@,Truck:%@,%@,%@",
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"Car1"] ?: @"",
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"Car2"] ?: @"",
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"Car3"] ?: @"",
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"Truck1"] ?: @"",
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"Truck2"] ?: @"",
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"Truck3"] ?: @""];
```

This way, if you have never set one of the keys before, it would be replaced by an empty string.

Though, I agree with **0x7fffffff** I would rather use an array of dictionaries for that feature. User Defaults must be used when you need persistence of your data, I'm not sure if it's your case.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. Sadly I have to have the data saved :(. Also, I have a question why exactly does this work. Never seen a function like it.

Comment: Glad it helped you :) `?:` is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), means it replaces a more complicated expression. e.g `a ?: b` replaces `if (a != nil) a; else b;`

Comment: @TwoFace it's called a turnary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, personally I don't think you should be using NSUserDefaults for this. What you should look into doing is creating one custom data structure to house all the information and then storing it into a plist in the documents directory.

By doing things this way, you can make an array of dictionaries where each dictionary contains the name of the car/truck, a key to tell if the object is a car or a truck, and a key to determine if the car/truck is currently selected. This way, when it comes time to format the email, you can just define a simple loop to count up and list out the cars and trucks.